# Why would environment variables in a bash script be overwritten using eval echo?

Tags: bash, eval, circleci

I'm writing a bash script based on a CircleCI orb's source code, and I'm confused why a subset of environment variables in a bash script would be set to `eval echo` of themselves.

For example, what would be the purpose of this line?

```bash
ORB_EVAL_REPO=$(eval echo "${ORB_EVAL_REPO}")
```

Here is the source code:

https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/aws-ecr#orb-source

As a full example, there are five environment variables set on lines 705-709, but only two of the variables are set using `eval echo` on lines 691-692, even though the variables are used in the same way on lines 699-702:

```yaml
command: |
    #!/bin/bash
    ORB_EVAL_REGION=$(eval echo "${ORB_EVAL_REGION}") # line 691
    ORB_EVAL_REPO=$(eval echo "${ORB_EVAL_REPO}")

    if [ "$ORB_VAL_PUBLIC_REGISTRY" == "1" ]; then
        echo "set-repository-policy is not supported on public repos"
        exit 1
    else
        aws ecr set-repository-policy \
            --profile "${ORB_VAL_PROFILE_NAME}" \ # line 699
            --region "${ORB_EVAL_REGION}" \
            --repository-name "${ORB_EVAL_REPO}" \
            --policy-text "file://${ORB_VAL_REPO_POLICY_PATH}"
    fi
environment:
    ORB_EVAL_REGION: <<parameters.region>> # line 705
    ORB_EVAL_REPO: <<parameters.repo>>
    ORB_VAL_PROFILE_NAME: <<parameters.profile-name>>
    ORB_VAL_PUBLIC_REGISTRY: <<parameters.public-registry>>
    ORB_VAL_REPO_POLICY_PATH: <<parameters.repo-policy-path>>
```

So far, I've:

- read the documentation for `eval`
- read StackOverflow answers to questions about the use cases of `eval`
- tried to infer the purpose of `eval echo` from the specific source code I'm reading
- searched for `"=$(eval echo "` on GitHub to try to find other examples

I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

Comment: The second time that config uses those variables, it's using the result of the `eval echo`, because the previous lines are overwriting the variables. I wasn't able to find relevant comments on their GitHub, but it seems to be a requirement for the Orb 11 format (as per [this commit message](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/aws-sam-serverless-orb/pull/40/commits/744830a798dab2328faf62402b968dfe6d2c6866)), possibly to do with how variables are passed in at runtime (but don't quote me on that!).

Comment: please remove those line numbers. See [Why is there no line numbering in code sections?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252559/995714). Just put a comment in the code to indicate the line you're talking about

Comment: @phuclv In this case I don't think it matters much; you would need the whole YAML file to repro anyway. (But the OP should review the guidance for providing a [mre]. But again, in this particular case, the "why" is more important than the "how".)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eval echo "$var"` expands variables in `$var`. Example:

```
a=" 12 "
b=' a  $a  b  '
echo "/$b/"      # prints: / a  $a  b  /
eval echo "/$b/" # prints: / a 12 b /
```

Side effects are trimming (removing) multiple spaces and that it may fail with special characters like `|` or a `'`.

Comment: Ah, I get it. So for example, at the start of the script the value of `ORB_EVAL_REGION` could be `"$AWS_REGION"` or `"us-east-1"`. Either way, after running `eval echo "${ORB_EVAL_REGION}"` the value will then be `"us-east-1"`. Thank you.